Azure CDN rule engine - work with redirect and path
I need to make sure that every time my url starts with /file it is directed to / (the root) but keeping the rest of the url the same, example -> /file/item.txt -> /item.txt, how can I do this? (I tried with rewrite and it didn't work, but with redirect it works, I just need to set this broadly and automatically)
tried with rewrite and it didn't work

Match Condition: Begins with /file
Action:  Redirect  with Destionation path = {url_path:5}
redirect rule
Explanation: {var:x} returns the variable with an offset, i.e. cuts of the first x symbols.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rule-set-server-variables#server-variable-format
